# How to execute statement after finishing the first one in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I have a following code in jQuery

```
$.when($("#tbl").block({ message: 'Loading...' })).done(    
    $("#tbl > tbody > tr").each(function (i) {
        var cost = $(this).find("#Cost_" + i + "__Cost").val();

        $(this).find("#Cost_" + i + "__Cost").val(cost).change();
    }));
```

I am trying to block first and then copy the value of one cell to another in the table until its done copying. But some reason block is only work after looping is finish.

How can I block before entering in the loop in this case?

TIA

Comment: Does `.done` not expect a callback *function*? That is, shouldn't you do `.done(function() { ... });` instead of your current `.done( ... )`. ?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thanks for quick reply. I changed the code like you said but still no change. Doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the `.when` or `.block` functions, however reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) it is said "If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached **will be executed immediately.**", which seems to apply to your case. I cannot find anything about `block`. If block is synchronous you can just execute it first, followed by your loop (get rid of `.when` / `.done` entirely).

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers It looks like `.block` is the BlockUI plugin, http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element. It is indeed synchronous

Comment: @Shai I see. Then the solution would probably just be `$("#tbl").block(); **copy loop here**; $("#tbl").unblock();`. If anyone wants to write an answer about it go ahead :-)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Done. If that's not right I think we've both misunderstood the question... Equally it'd have to be a pretty large table to need visual indication that it's copying a few values!

Answer (score 1):

`.block()`, from the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element), is synchronous, so you don't want to be using `$.when()` here.

Try:

```
$("#tbl").block({ message: 'Loading...' });

$("#tbl > tbody > tr").each(function (i) {
    var cost = $(this).find("#Cost_" + i + "__Cost").val();

    $(this).find("#Cost_" + i + "__Cost").val(cost).change();
});

$("#tbl").unblock();
```

Comment: @Shai Thanks for trying to help me but this is not working. It is doing the same thing.